# Ringtones directory won't update in settings

Tags: ringtone

I removed some of the stock ringtones (from my ROM) that I didn't want from /system/media/audio/ringtones and added some new ones that I got from the xda forums via my SD card and RootExplorer.

When I open the Sound/Default Ringtone menus in settings, some of the old ringtones are listed and new ones are listed as well, none of them play. The only ones that do are the few that I left in /system/media/audio/ringtones and a few stored on my SD card.

How can I fix this issue so that my phone recognises that all files are in their proper directories?

Comment: Have you restarted your phone since you replaced them?

Comment: Yes. Twice already. There's no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update the ring tone directory, the media scanner has to run. Usually restarting the phone will do this, but if media scanner is not checking that directory when the device starts you can try to create a file in the sdcard ringtone directory with an app that triggers media scanner. I think Astro File Manager will trigger it.

If that doesn't work, you could try clearing the cache (I assume root since you are using root explorer and deleting system ringtones), the system may be caching that information and thinks they are still there.

Comment: The media scanner running fixed it! Although the media scanner ran when I restarted my phone previously, but for some reason the directory didn't update. Would that be because of the cache?

Comment: it could be because of caching, I am not 100% sure it caches the data in /cache, but it makes sense to me that it would because it scans the directory and doesn't update it unless it rescans.

Comment: Installing Astro and browsing to the file fixed it for me.